# Lifecycle of service deployed as separate APK

Tags: android, service, lifecycle

I developed a dummy service and a test application that uses it - using bindService.
The service and test app are deployed as separate APKs.

After the test app is terminated (it unbinds the service) from the service perspective I see calls to onUnbind and onDestroy respectively.
But still the service is listed as *Cached background process* under Settings -> Apps -> Running (show cached processes). The test app is not listed as expected.

I thought that Android will terminate the application providing service when the service is unbound and destroyed?
How to terminate it or is it a standard Android caching mechanism even though it was destroyed?

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that Android will terminate the application providing service when the service is unbound and destroyed?

The service process would behave no differently than would any other SDK app's process. Once there are no running components (in your case, once there are no bound connections), the process will remain in memory until Android needs that memory for some other purpose. How quickly the process will be terminated therefore depends on environmental conditions.